# What is a very efficient way to export data from a GridView to Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

I tested a few samples of VB code to export data from a GridView to Excel.  All were way too slow to be practical.  I'm dealing with 200k rows, or more, in the GridView.  Everything loads from SQL Server into the GridView very quickly, but to get it from the GridView to Excel is painfully slow.  I'd like to know if there is a fast way to move the data into Excel, like loading everything into an array, instead of looping through 200k rows of data.

Or, could I write to a CSV, and open that in Excel?  If that's pretty fast that could certainly be an option for me.

Thanks for sharing your wisdom experts.

Comment: There are several ways.  The way this is posed, you are asking for opinions.

Comment: I think CSV is the fastest, but IIRC `Excel.Range.Value2` allows you to send an array, rather than filling each cell one at a time.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for opinions, but rather a working solution.  @SSS, I'll look at that when I get to the office tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: I posted example code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CSV is the fastest, but `Excel.Range.Value2` allows you to send an array, rather than filling each cell one at a time:

```
Dim xl As New Excel.Application 'always use a variable to reference Excel, otherwise it may stay in memory, hidden.'
Dim b As Excel.Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add 'do not use b = New Excel.Workbook, as this can cause a memory leak'
Dim s As Excel.Worksheet

xl.Visible = True
Dim sLast As Excel.Worksheet = b.Worksheets(b.Worksheets.Count)
b.Worksheets.Add(, sLast)
s = b.Worksheets(1) '1-based'
Dim o(199999, 1) As Object
For i As Integer = 0 To 199999
  o(i, 0) = i.ToString
  o(i, 1) = (200000 - i).ToString
Next i
s.Name = "ExcelDemo"
Dim r As Excel.Range = s.Range("A1", "B200000")
r.Value2 = o
s.Activate()
Dim strFilename As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Junk" 'N.B. extension automatically added'
b.SaveAs(strFilename)
strFilename = b.FullName 'get full filename'
xl.Quit()
MsgBox(strFilename & " saved")
```

Comment: Above code creates a 200K row file pretty quickly on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.